# Count of records; trying to show related data

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp, find

I am struggling with a beginners problem in my current application development. I have records containing trainingplans which are related to different syllabi in a another model.

What I try to do, is to show how many trainingplans are active for all the syllabi I have. In my controller i tried it with the following find statement:

`$trainingplans = $this->Trainingplans->find('all', array('group' =>'syllabus_id','fields' => array('count(*)','syllabus_id')));`

The return looks like:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [count(*)] => 5
                )
            [Trainingplans] => Array
                (
                    [syllabus_id] => 1
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [count(*)] => 2
                )
            [Trainingplans] => Array
                (
                    [syllabus_id] => 2
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [count(*)] => 1
                )
            [Trainingplans] => Array
                (
                    [syllabus_id] => 5
                )
        )
)
```

So this is quite close to what I wanted, but I need `syllabus.name` with it.

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are correctly joined, add Syllabus.name in the 'fields' param. 
If this is not enough, try to raise recursivity before the find

```
$this->Trainingplans->recursive = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i´ve already tried this. Maybe you are right, so i will check if the models are correctly joined. Best regards cdjw

Comment: Thanks, that was the little push i´ve needed ! Checked my models and now i am fine. sorry for being that stupid, thanks for your help.